# Counting rows with a group by is not distinct across two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case, distinct

I have a SQL query that is trying to create a billing report where each row should be

`customer | account | api1 | api2 | api3`

the ApiCalled table tracks which customer and account permutation called which API.

Each customer can have multiple accounts and I want to show the count for the rows for each of the different end points grouped by customer and account. Below is what I have so far.

```
    SELECT 
        c.Name As Customer, 
        sa.Name as account, 
        COUNT(CASE cuec.EndpointCalled WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) api1,
        COUNT(CASE cuec.EndpointCalled WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) api2,
        COUNT(CASE cuec.EndpointCalled WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) api3
    FROM
        Customers.ApiCalled cuec
        INNER JOIN Customers.Customers c
            ON c.CustomerId = cuec.CustomerId
       INNER JOIN Customers.Accounts sa
            ON sa.CustomerId = cuec.CustomerId
    GROUP BY
         sa.Name, c.Name
```

The issue I'm having is that in the situation is that when a customer has say 2 accounts and has called an endpoint once from both accounts I would expect to have results like this

```
customer | account | api1 | api2 | api3
cust1    | acc1    | 1    |  0   |  0
cust1    | acc2    | 1    |  0   |  0
```

but instead I am getting this

```
customer | account | api1 | api2 | api3
cust1    | acc1    | 2    |  0   |  0
cust1    | acc2    | 2    |  0   |  0
```

Perhaps I have put myself into a hole by putting the Case inside the count. Some help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: At a guess your joins look wrong, you should probably be outer joining to the `ApiCalled` table possibly using *apply* and aggregating *before* joining.

Comment: Nowhere in your JOINs are you referencing the "account" - you are only referencing the Customer ID.  How does the query know which "account" was used for the API call?  I'm guessing that if (hopefully) your "ApiCalled" table also has the "AccountId" recorded, then the FROM section of your query would need to be ... FROM Customers.ApiCalled cuec INNER JOIN Customers.Customers c ON c.CustomerId = cuec.CustomerId INNER JOIN Customers.Accounts sa ON sa.CustomerId = cuec.CustomerId AND sa.AccountId = cuec.AccountId ...

Comment: What @Stu said. ApiCalled should have an Account column so you know which account called which API

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stu and Craig in the comments I revisited my original query by breaking it down into a sub query and then joining on the Name of the customer and the Account which worked,

In the process I realised my error and it should have been

```
INNER JOIN Customers.Accounts sa
            ON sa.AccountId= cuec.AccountId
```

I was incorrectly using the customer Id when joining on the accounts table instead of the account id